# Find the variables that contribute the most into group variances

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I have two groups with different numbers of observations. Here is the toy example:

```
obs1_1 <- c(1,0,13,5,0,2,6,7,0,2)
obs2_1 <- c(0,0,13,0,0,2,1,0,4,3)
obs3_1 <- c(2,1,10,5,8,4,6,5,1,2)
obs4_1 <- c(1,0,13,4,0,2,6,7,0,2)
obs5_1 <- c(0,1,13,0,4,4,1,0,4,3)

group1 <- data.frame(obs1_1, obs2_1, obs3_1, obs4_1, obs5_1)
rownames(group1) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10")

obs1_2 <- c(11,1,11,5,0,2,6,7,0,2)
obs2_2 <- c(11,1,11,0,0,1,1,0,4,1)
obs3_2 <- c(11,1,10,1,8,1,1,5,1,2)
obs4_2 <- c(11,1,13,4,0,2,6,0,0,2)
obs5_2 <- c(10,0,13,0,3,0,1,0,4,3)
obs6_2 <- c(10,1,13,2,0,4,1,3,4,3)

group2 <- data.frame(obs1_2, obs2_2, obs3_2, obs4_2, obs5_2, obs6_2)
rownames(group2) <- c("var1", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var7", "var8", "var11", "var12", "var13", "var14")
```

All the values are continuous and I don't think they are normally distributed. Also, not all the variables present in both groups.
I am thinking to use Wilcoxon sum rank test to analyze differences between the groups. But I am confused how to do it in R as I have too many variables.

How to find the variables that contribute the most into group variances? In this toy example, variables var1, var3, and var4 have the biggest difference between group. So, I guess, they should be the ones that contribute to the groups variance. Plus those that present in just one group.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both data frames and do a loop like this:

```
library(dplyr)

# Transposing the dataframes

g1 <- as.data.frame(t(group1))
g2 <- as.data.frame(t(group2))

# Melting to have a variable  and value columns

g1 <- reshape2::melt(g1, measure = colnames(g1))
g1$group <- "g1"

g2 <- reshape2::melt(g2, measure = colnames(g2))
g2$group <- "g2"


# Binding both groups

df <- rbind(g1, g2)

# Creating an empty list for output

wsr <- list()

for (i in unique(df$variable)) {
  d <- df %>% filter(variable == i)
  wsr[[i]] <- ifelse(length(unique(d$group)) == 2, 
                      wilcox.test(value~group, data = d),
                     NA)
  
}

# If you just need the p.value 

wsr_p <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))

for (i in unique(df$variable)) {
  d <- filter(df, variable == i)
  s <- ifelse(length(unique(d$group)) == 2, 
                     wilcox.test(value~group, data = d)[["p.value"]],
                     NA)
  wsr_p <- rbind(wsr_p, data.frame(variable = i, p = s))
  
}

wsr_p

variable           p
1      var1 0.006349039
2      var2          NA
3      var3 0.004390260
4      var4 0.007135044
5      var5 0.847768887
6      var6          NA
7      var7 0.156039402
8      var8 0.516063755
9      var9          NA
10    var10          NA
11    var11          NA
12    var12          NA
13    var13          NA
14    var14          NA
```